# Equivalent of generic NUnit.Framework.TestFixture in xUnit

Tags: xunit

In NUnit, we can create a generic test fixture.

```
[TestFixture(typeof(double))]
[TestFixture(typeof(float))]
public class ServiceTests<T>
{
    private readonly MyService<T> myService = new();
    /* ... */
}
```

Has xUnit any equivalent of this?

I'm trying to test a generic service and now I need to create separate classes to test it for many generic types.

```
public abstract class DoubleServiceTests : ServiceTests<double> 
{}

public abstract class FloatServiceTests : ServiceTests<float> 
{}

public abstract class ServiceTests<T>
{
    private readonly MyService<T> myService = new();
    /* ... */
}
```

This is a solution that I'm currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe usage of *Theory* attribute will help.

*Theory* allows injection of test data inside a test. So some test from *ServiceTests* may look like this:

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(typeof(float))]
[InlineData(typeof(double))]
public void SomeTestMethod(Type t)
{
    // make use of type t
}
```

More [info] on *Theory* related attributes in xunit.

Comment: There still would be a problem with the creation of a generic service. I know there are some tricks to make test generic in xUnit but then I need to do all generic work inside the test method (or methods called by test method).

Comment: Got you, sorry that couldn't help.